# Avoid variable duplication using fork() in C

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, fork, shared-memory

I am implementing a server that serves multiple clients and I need some server's variable to be in shared memory so a client actually sees what another client has eventually edited.

I tried looking around but I didn't understand if there is any way to achieve this by using fork() or I totally need to change the way I handle clients. In particular I don't know if I should implement piped processes or threads. Also, what is the simpler way?

This is my code after declaring **int var** in the main:

```
while(1) {
        printf("Waiting connection...\n");
        if ((connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
            perror("Accept Error");
            exit(1);
        }

        if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
            close (listenfd);
            printf("Variable: %d\n", var); // var = 0
            var = 1;
            printf("Variable: %d\n", var); // var = 1
            exit(0);
        }

        close(connfd);
    }
```

When I connect with another client I see again var = 0 because the child generates a copy of the parent process.

Tried using static or declaring global variables outside of the main() but as I understood it has no effect.

Comment: "I need some server's variable to be in shared memory" - that would be the answer to what you're trying to do, so its unclear what the question is. Shared data between processes has to be "shared" somehow, and shared memory is a common choice.

Comment: Looking on the web I found this http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html but I don't know if I am looking for the right thing since it talks about segments and similar things

Comment: It looks correct. Check the links in Basile's answer as well. Hunt around on this site enough and others and you're likely going to find reasonable examples of how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fork` does not duplicate *variables* but the *entire [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space)* (by definition of `fork`) of the invoking [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29).

You might want to use some shared memory, but then you should care about [synchronization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_%28computer_science%29).  Read [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) and [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) (you could share some memory using [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) but you need to synchronize anyway).

Maybe you don't need to fork, but you just want to have several *threads* sharing the *same* address space. Read [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) and a good [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). Then you'll also should care about synchronization, probably using mutexes.

You could also (and instead) use some other form of [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), consider using [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s and have some [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) around a multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

In a server/client scenario, you might have some request and protocol to query (from inside clients) some state variable (inside the server).

PS. The main issue is not sharing data, it is synchronization and [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) avoidance.

Comment: Yes, I knew this. Indeed I wrote "generates a copy of the parent process", anyways I have no idea how to start with the function you wrote me, could you make me a very fast example and show how to "send" the variables in the "shared" space?

Comment: Sorry, you need a couple of hours of reading and experimenting. I just can't make a fast example. *synchronization* (and *deadlock avoidance*) are significant issues.

Comment: Nevermind, just read your updated answer and will take a look on the tutorial because at this point, I don't really think I will need to use fork but create several threads. Thank you for the complete answer and support

Comment: [`mmap(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) with `MAP_SHARED` is another option. Probably less than a couple of hours reading is required.

Comment: @mhawke: What is tricky to understand is the necessity of synchronization, and how to implement it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch can you tell me if I can use select() and co. to use threads?

Comment: `select` is IMHO nearly obsolete. Use `poll`  instead. And yes, you could use it with threads.

Comment: On my University teacher's documentation I just read it is suggested to use this function. Since I don't trust very much whatever he says, would you tell me why do you consider it obsolete?

Comment: Google for "C10K problem". The `fd_set` type for `select` has a compile-time limited size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70157/discussion-between-wiredmark-and-basile-starynkevitch).